# JQuery date type , Sybase date type sent to CF function

Tags: jquery, sql, coldfusion, sybase

I have a Sybase SP which takes a date as the sole argument and returns information about an order.  I get the date from a JQuery datepicker on a CF page - which is formatted to yy-mm-dd.    The SP defaults to getDate() when none is entered.  When I enter a date on the form everything works fine.  When I do not send a date - the date field is left blank - I get a CF error telling me that the argument is not of type date.  I know the SP is sending a datetime value but how can I get the CF function to recognize it?

In the SP...

```
declare @order_dt datetime 

If @order_dt IS NULL
BEGIN
SELECT @order_dt = getDate()
END
```

In the cfc...

```
<cfargument name="order_dt" type="date" required="true" hint="order date to search for" >
```

and

```
 <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" dbvarname="@order_dt" value="#order_dt#" null="No">
```

On the .cfm page...

```
<!--JQuery datepicker  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
           $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val()
   });
```

And the form looks like this:

```
<form id="xxxxForm">
<label for="date1">Pick a Date... </label>
<br>
<p><input type="text" id="datepicker" value="" name="date1"></p>
Then choose 'Search'...<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
<br>
<br>

</form>
```

How can I get CF to recognize this as a good value?  I was thinking perhaps if I declare @order_dt as just a date??

Comment: If you don't send in a date to the cfc method, you will continue to get that error because the date argument is required and must be of type date. If you want it to allow no date, make it not required and give it a default value that is a date so that it will pass the procparam check.

Comment: Agreed. Either set `required="false"` or use `default="#now()#"` in your `<cfargument>`.

Comment: Also, I assume you want only a date from CF and not a datetime? For a datetime value you need to use `CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP` in your `<cfprocparam>`

Comment: Gaaaa! I hate it when I try too hard and miss the obvious. Thanks for pointing it out. Yes, I just want a date. I think now() will work.  I changed the datatype in the proc to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> <cfargument name="order_dt" type="date" required="true"
```

When you leave the date field blank, the submitted value is an empty string "". An empty string is not a valid `date`. That is why CF complains when you try and invoke the function.

As mentioned in the comments, you could use `required="false"` or `default="#now()#"`. But for it to work as you expect, you must *also* omit the argument when the date is left blank. If you pass anything to the function, even an empty string, the `default` will not kick in. But validation will. So you will still get the same error.

Another option is to change the argument type to `string`. Then validate inside the function. If the supplied value is not a valid date, either replace it with `now()`

```
   <cfargument name="order_dt" type="string" default="">

   <!--- simplistic date validation for illustration --->
   <cfif NOT isDate(arguments.order_dt)>
       <cfset arguments.order_dt = now()>
   </cfif>
```

OR just pass `NULL` to the stored procedure

```
   <cfargument name="order_dt" type="string" default="">
   ...

   <cfprocparam type="In" value="#arguments.order_dt#" 
         null="#not isDate(arguments.order_dt)#" ....>
```

On a side note, `dbvarname` was deprecated a while back. In recent versions it does nothing. Only positional parameters are supported.

Comment: I think we are still running CFMX7 so maybe it is still necessary?  I could very well use now() come to think of it.   And the NULL could  work since I default to getDate() in the SP once it gets there. That makes sense from the user's perspective...usually they will want the current date value.  Thanks

Comment: The docs say it was deprecated back in MX: *"Changed the dbvarname attribute behavior: it is now ignored for all drivers. ColdFusion uses JDBC 2.2 and does not support named parameters."* So it probably does nothing in your version too.